# How to setting a proxy on Azure(version 1.1.2) in java develop?

Tags: java, azure, authentication, proxy, azure-web-app-service

I am use follow code, but always has errors:

```
    public static void connect(CloudCredentials credentials, final CloudProxy proxy) throws Exception {
    ApplicationTokenCredentials azCredential = new ApplicationTokenCredentials(credentials.getClientID(), 
            credentials.getTenantID(), credentials.getClientKey(), AzureEnvironment.AZURE);
    try {
        Configurable config = Azure.configure()
                .withConnectionTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .withReadTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        if (proxy != null) {
            config.withProxy(new Proxy(Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(proxy.getProxyHost(), proxy
                    .getProxyPort())));
            if (proxy.getProxyUsername() != null && proxy.getProxyUsername().trim().length() > 0) {
                Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
                    @Override
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(proxy.getProxyUsername(), proxy.getProxyPassword()
                                .toCharArray());
                    }
                });
                config.withProxyAuthenticator(new JavaNetAuthenticator());
            }
        }
        Authenticated authenticate = config.authenticate(azCredential);
        authenticate.withSubscription(credentials.getSubscription()).getCurrentSubscription().displayName();
        System.out.println(authenticate);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

```
[pool-1-thread-1] ERROR com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext - [Correlation ID: ] Request to acquire token failed.
java.io.IOException: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authentication Required"
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.doTunneling(HttpURLConnection.java:2124)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:183)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1316)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1291)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AdalOAuthRequest.configureHeaderAndExecuteOAuthCall(AdalOAuthRequest.java:140)
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AdalOAuthRequest.send(AdalOAuthRequest.java:83)
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AdalTokenRequest.executeOAuthRequestAndProcessResponse(AdalTokenRequest.java:80)
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext.acquireTokenCommon(AuthenticationContext.java:818)
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext.access$100(AuthenticationContext.java:66)
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext$1.call(AuthenticationContext.java:174)
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext$1.call(AuthenticationContext.java:163)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authentication Required"
```

but the proxy I am sure it's ok. i have another test code. it work well:

```
    String a = "111";
    System.out.print(a.toCharArray());

    Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
        public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication("test", "111".toCharArray());
        }
    });
    URLConnection connection;
    try {
        connection = new URL(
                "http://devio.us/~ricky/stackoverflow-protected/nothingtosee.html")
                .openConnection(new Proxy(Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("192.168.1.59", 808)));

        System.out.println(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                connection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8")).readLine());

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

I don't want to use System.setProperty to set proxy because the all java connected will through proxy.
and in Azure doc I don't find any proxy information.
who can help me? thank you very much.

Comment: Any progress?Does my answer helps you?

Comment: sure, very useful. thank you very much!

Comment: You could mark my answer for others' reference,thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> Now, proxies requiring Basic authentication when setting up a tunnel
>   for HTTPS will no longer succeed by default. If required, this
>   authentication scheme can be reactivated by removing Basic from the
>   jdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes networking property, or by
>   setting a system property of the same name to "" ( empty ) on the
>   command line.

You can find it from [Disable Basic authentication for HTTPS tunneling](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u111-relnotes-3124969.html).

So,you could find your `net.properties` file in your `jdk/jre/lib directory`.
(For me,it's `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib`).

Then change the variables

```
jdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes 
jdk.http.auth.proxying.disabledSchemes
```

to empty like:

```
jdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=
jdk.http.auth.proxying.disabledSchemes=
```

Please retry your code. Any concern,please feel free to let me kown.